# Components/basis of parallel transported vectors

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, change-of-basis, geodesic, connections

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $p,q,r\in M$ points on the manifold. The vectors $u\in T_pM$, $v\in T_qM$ are then transported from $p$ resp. $q$ to $r$ along geodesics according to the parallel transport equation.

Suppose $\tilde{u}, \tilde{v}\in T_rM$ are those solutions. Can I assume these transported vectors are given in the same basis? If not, how can I transform them into the same base so I can e.g. add them? Is it even possible to formulate it in general?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**:
I've come up with a work around, and maybe there isn't a simpler solution.

Suppose $\{e_i\}$ is an orthogonal basis of $T_rM$ and $\{e_j\}$ an OB of $T_pM$. We can parallel transport $\{e_i\}$ from $r$ to $p$ where it is an OB of $T_pM$, but in general $\{\tilde e_i\}\neq\{e_j\}$.

We can then write a vector in both bases $v=v^je_j=\tilde v^i\tilde e_i$, and calculate the components of the transported base as

$\tilde v^i=\dfrac{v^k}{\tilde e_ie^k}$

These components don't change under the parallel transport back from $p$ to $r$.

Comment: What is "the parallel transport equation" you are working with?

Comment: Maybe I didn't frame it right, what I meant was the solution to $\nabla_{\gamma'}v$ which connects $p$ and $r$, with the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$